# GWT with HTML5 desktop notifications (webkitNotifications)

Tags: html, gwt, notifications, jsni, html5-notifications

I am trying to implement HTML5 desktop notifications using GWT.  Currently this is not supported with the GWT libraries, so I am using native javascript from within GWT(JSNI).  I thought this would be fairly straight forward, however I am not having any success.  I am using chrome and have tried in dev mode and a deployed app.  Below is the code that I am using.

NOTE:  the javascript code came from http://playground.html5rocks.com/#simple_notifications and it worked fine in chrome.

Has anyone got this to work??

```
 public native void requestPermission() /*-{
         $wnd.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();      
     }-*/;

  public native void createJSNotification(String iconUrl, String title, String body) /*-{
    $wnd.webkitNotifications.createNotification(iconUrl, title, body).show();
}-*/;
```

Comment: Don't know if this helps but can you try to add the requestPermission() in a  new method in your .html page and call that new method from your gwt app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, everthing you do looks fine to me. I tried the example and ran it with GWT and it worked. The only thing I noticed is that it can take some time till the Notification shows if you are running in debugg code:

Here is my GWT code:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    {
        Button bt_Permission = new Button("Request Permission");
        bt_Permission.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                requestPermission();
            }
        });
        RootPanel.get().add(bt_Permission);
    }
    {
        Button bt_ShowNotification = new Button("Show Notification");
        bt_ShowNotification.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                showNotification();
            }
        });
        RootPanel.get().add(bt_ShowNotification);
    }
}

public native void requestPermission() /*-{
    $wnd.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
}-*/;

public native void  showNotification() /*-{
    var text = 'You got a new email from someone@test.com'
    if ($wnd.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) {
        // note the show()
        $wnd.webkitNotifications.createNotification('',
                'Plain Text Notification', text).show();
    } else {
        alert('You have to click on "Set notification permissions for this page" first to be able to receive notifications.');
    }
}-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan.  I was not asking for permission in an asynchonous way.    That was my problem.  Works great.

Comment: had this problem once too, where I denied the premission, and then it never asked me again (even when I called requestPermission();). Had to clean my browser cash bevore could aske again...